# Could I host static website using awscli s3 website command in IBM COS - S3 API?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

```
aws --endpoint-url=https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net 
     s3 website s3://mytestbucket --index-document index.html
     --error-document error.html
```

> An error occurred (UnsupportedOperation) when calling the PutBucketWebsite operation: The operation requested is not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static website hosting is not currently supported by the COS implementation of the S3 API.  A full list of [all S3 API operations supported by COS can be found in the 'API Overview' section of the documentation](https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/crs-operations.html).